# Update table A's column with oldest value from joined column B

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have :

```
post(id, date)
comment(id, post_id, date, checked)
```

I'd like to update posts that :

- have a null date column
- have a comment with checked as true

with the date of the oldest comment having checked as true, without using a subquery for performance reason, assuming I'm using a large data set.

So far I have

```
update post p
set date = c.date
from post p2
         join comment c on p2.id = c.id and c.checked is true
where p.date is null
```

but it seems to update the date with the latest entry, and the ones that don't have a comment with checked as true also get affected

POST

| id | date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | null |
| 2 | null |
| 3 | null |

COMMENT

| id | post_id | date | checked |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2020-01-01 | true |
| 2 | 1 | 2020-05-01 | true |
| 3 | 2 | 2020-03-01 | false |

POST AFTER UPDATE

| id | date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-01-01 |
| 2 | null |
| 3 | null |

Posts 2 and 3 don't get updated because they don't have any comments with checked as true

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: "without using a subquery for performance reason" - there is no reason, per se, that a subquery is going to create bad performance. It's bad to make assumptions about performance without first working out what performance is acceptable and second measuring the simplest code that works to see if its good enough. Remember in SQL you tell the system *what you want*, not *how to do it*. So if two queries are *logically* equivalent but one is expressed as a subquery and the other is not, the system *should* be able to produce identical plans for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to `UPDATE .... FROM` subquery by using `ROW_NUMBER` window function to get oldest `DATE` from `comment` table.

```
UPDATE post p
SET date = c.date
FROM (
   SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY DATE) rn
   FROM comment
) c 
where p.date is null AND 
rn = 1 AND
p.id = c.post_id AND
c.checked = true
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=7aff40b79cb194c042f5ae30864541d0)

Comment: any way to do this using joins ?

Comment: @adaba You don't need to use `Join` keyword in your case, this case already associates two tables by where condition. the `JOIN` is unnecessary

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that you have put `c.checked is true` in the **JOIN** clause when it should be in the **WHERE** clause.
Please check the following update query:

```
update post p
set date = c.date
from post p2
join comment c on p2.id = c.id 
where p.date is null
and c.checked is true;
```

Comment: all rows are still affected and the date is still the most recent one